# Как сравнить два объекта разных экземпляров класса PHP

Tags: php

Отсортировать по costs, а потом по name

```
[5] =>  Object1
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => abb
        [costs] => 33
    )

[6] =>  Object2
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => bcc
        [costs] => 55
    )

[4] =>  Object3
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => fff
        [costs] => 66
    )

[3] => Object4
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => fff
        [costs] => 55

function mySort($a,$b) {                

   if($a->costs > $b->costs) return -1;   - работает
   if($a->costs < $b->costs) return 1;    - работает
   if ($a->costs == $b->costs)  {         - не сравнивает    
      }
```

uasort($array,"mySort");

```
      array (
        4 => 
          FixedMonthlyCostPaidService::__set_state(array(
           'id' => 'service5',
           'name' => 'YouTube',
           'costs' => 8064,
         )),
       2 => 
          FixedHourlyCostPaidService::__set_state(array(
           'id' => 'service3',
           'name' => 'Mandrill',
           'costs' => 8063.9999999999991,
          )),
      0 => 
           FixedHourlyCostPaidService::__set_state(array(
          'id' => 'service1',
          'name' => 'Google Orkut',
          'costs' => 7920,
          )),
       5 => 
          FixedMonthlyCostPaidService::__set_state(array(
         'id' => 'service6',
         'name' => 'LinkedIn',
         'costs' => 6863,
         )),
       1 => 
          FixedHourlyCostPaidService::__set_state(array(
          'id' => 'service2',
          'name' => 'Google Voice',
          'costs' => 6768,
         )),
      3 => 
          FixedHourlyCostPaidService::__set_state(array(
         'id' => 'service4',
         'name' => 'Google Finance',
         'costs' => 5616,
         )),
      6 => 
         FixedMonthlyCostPaidService::__set_state(array(
          'id' => 'service7',
          'name' => 'Google Building Maker',
          'costs' => 5347,
        )),
```

)

вывод должен быть:

```
service3 / Mandrill / 8064
service5 / YouTube / 8064
service1 / Google Orkut / 7920
service6 / LinkedIn / 6863
service2 / Google Voice / 6768
service4 / Google Finance / 5616
service7 / Google Building Maker / 5347
```

Comment: что означает работает/не работает?  и если вам не сложно, выложите вывод от var_export, а не print_r

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368027/php-sort-an-object-by-two-criteria

Comment: не сравнивает - означает, что вы туда не попадаете?

Comment: где вызов сортировки то?

Comment: djn nfr - https://eval.in/781252

Comment: Как поменять местами service3 / Mandrill / 8064 с service5 / YouTube / 8064

Comment: a и b в strcmp поменяйте

Comment: Вот Сравнение объектов http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.object-comparison.php 
А в вашем примере не объекты сравниваются а их поля (свойства),Которые имеют примитивный тип (str|int).

Comment: В принципе в вашем сравнение mySort ... return ...  можно заменить на (mySort($a,$b){return $a->costs - $b->costs }).